# How to use JSONata to change JSON response restructure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsonata

I have one JSON data that I want to restructure the data using JSONata query

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "enterpriseid": 53898,
            "enterprise": " Absolute F and B Facilities Management LLC ",
            "bookingvalue": 46
        },
        {
           
            "enterpriseid": 53898,
            "enterprise": " Absolute F and B Facilities Management LLC ",
            "bookingvalue": 275
        },
        {
            "enterpriseid": 53898,
            "enterprise": " Absolute F and B Facilities Management LLC ",
            "bookingvalue": 199.5
            
        },
        {
            "enterpriseid": 53899,
            "enterprise": " testing Buyer ",
            "bookingvalue": 200
            
        }
       
      
    ]
}
```

And I'm trying to use JSONata to change it to something more like this:

```
{
    "output": [
        {
            "enterpriseid": 53898,
            "enterprise": " Absolute F and B Facilities Management LLC ",
            "bookingvalue": 520.5
        },
        {
            "enterpriseid": 53899,
            "enterprise": " testing Buyer",
            "bookingvalue": 200
        }
    ]
}
```

i tried with this query but i am getting only enterpriseid and enterprise not getting bookingvalue

```
{
  
  "output": $distinct(response.{
    "enterpriseid" : enterpriseid,
    "enterprise": enterprise,
    "bookingvalue": $sum($filter(response, function($item) {$item.enterpriseid = enterpriseid}).bookingvalue)
  } )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [double dollar signs (`$$`)](https://docs.jsonata.org/programming#built-in-variables) to break out of `$distinct`'s context for the sum of all filtered items.

> `$$` The root of the input JSON. Only needed if you need to break out of
> the current context to temporarily navigate down a different path.

For example:

```
{
  "output": $distinct(response.{
    "enterpriseid" : enterpriseid,
    "enterprise": enterprise,
    "bookingvalue": $sum($filter($$.response, function($item) {$item.enterpriseid = enterpriseid}).bookingvalue)
  })
}
```

*(Note the double dollar sign `$$` usage inside of `$filter`.)*

Which outputs:

```
{
  "output": [
    {
      "enterpriseid": 53898,
      "enterprise": " Absolute F and B Facilities Management LLC ",
      "bookingvalue": 520.5
    },
    {
      "enterpriseid": 53899,
      "enterprise": " testing Buyer ",
      "bookingvalue": 200
    }
  ]
}
```

**Working Example:** https://try.jsonata.org/Y-7YTZ_eJ